# No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-menu

as the title suggest, I'm getting that error in at least 3 of the XML layout files, however, I dont see the attritube "showsAsAction" in any of those XML files, did I miss something or am I just blind?, here are the XML files in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registrar Asistencia" 
        android:onClick="registrarAsistencia"/>

     <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/listaAlumnos" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCuenta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cuenta"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCuenta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contraseña"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIniciarSesion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="iniciarSesion"
        android:text="Iniciar Sesion" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, I'm using Android 2.2 (API 8) as the target version. I know "showAsAction" was implemented in API 11, but I just cant find the issue here.

**Update:** The problems panel shows the following errors:

> Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\\Documents\Android\Registro de Asistencia\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Comment: @BinoyBabu Thanks for answering. Tried but unfortunately didnt work. In fact, I dont know why, but everytime I try to clean the project the R.java file is deleted and does not seems to be autogenerated again. Luckily I have a backup of the project folder. Any ideas on what could it be?

Comment: Maybe corrupted ADT plugin or Android SDK. Try reinstalling both.

Comment: Errors in your project. Check the errors panel. Should tell you warnings and errors alike. Reinstalling everything is to traumatic... Check for hidden errors first.

Comment: Check the Problems panel (Window->Show View ->Problems)

Comment: It does have 2 errors, I have updated the OP with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking in the right *.xml file? You seem to look for "showAsAction" in layout xmls, but it's parameter for the menu. Look rather into .../menu/your_activity.xml

The problem you are dealing with is connected with using target less than 4.0 and/or API less than 14.

So,

a) change those parameters,

b) change the value of showAsAction from "never" to "ifRoom".

Comment: Hey, just saw your answer, but I have solved this already, although you were right, I was looking at the wrong XMLs all the time!

Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I assumed you already got this. I answered for those who could be dealing with the same thing and not have an answer and have a hard time looking for it. Like me.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem when I forgot to add **appcompat-v7:+** to my project dependencies.  You can do it like this in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

And this is because I had the following in my menu.xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

When I removed the **xmlns:app** namespace and just used `android:showAsAction="never"`, I didn't need the appcompat-v7 library anymore.

Comment: here it says one must use a custom namespace for showAction http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Yeah I guess that would make sense on older devices.

Comment: I had it opposite way - Studio generated project for Android 2.2, but I later changed my mind and switched to 4.1. But there was this appcompat dependency in the project. It helped to remove it.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Wow, 2.2?  That is an old version of Android.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if you have used the resourceidentifier "ShowAsAction" in your XML.
This feature is available only from ver11 i guess. If you are trying to run the same on a lower API version this errror is produced.
SOLUTION ->>
Right click the project > Properties > Android> Build Target > Choose something greater than API 11

Answer (score 2):

you must choose an API 14 with version of 4.0 or grater  because any version below 4.0 does not contain in its package the **showAsAction** attribute

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is to use

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

instead where android is

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 1):

**ANDROID STUDIO**

if you are using **ANDROID STUDIO**...... use this fix

add

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

in menu tag instead of

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto "`

in **menu** tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you import your project from Android Studio to eclipse, just add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

In the head of xml, then it will all fix.